# Ember Data Nested Resources Tree Structure

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a slightly peculiar problem with loading my tree structure into Ember.

My models are:

```
book.js
  - parts: DS.hasMany('part', {inverse: 'book', async: true})

part.js
  - subparts: DS.hasMany('part', {inverse: 'parent_part', async: true}),
```

With the following API responses:

```
GET /api/books:
{
  books: [
    {id: 1, links: {parts: "/api/books/1/parts"}},
    ...
  ]
}

GET /api/books/1/parts:
{
  parts: [
  {
    id: 1,
    subparts: [10, 11]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    subparts: []
  }
  ]
}
```

The problem is in the tree nature of the parts: The book only has direct descendants id 1 and 2, but these have sub-parts on their own.
The structure as it is **works** but results in multiple sub-queries for each part that was not included in the `/books/1/parts` result. I want to avoid these queries, not only because of performance reasons but also because I will need additional query parameters which would get lost at this step... I know about `coalesceFindRequests` but it introduces new problems.

To rephrase the problem, Ember Data thinks that every `part` that is included in the `/books/1/parts` response should be added directly to the `book:parts` property. How can I still load all records of the parts tree at the same time?

I tried renaming the fields, but Ember Data assigns the records based on the model name, not the field name.

I fear that some creative adapter overriding will be necessary here. Any idea appreciated. The backend is completely under my control, so I could change things on that end, too.

Comment: Are you using the RESTAdapter (the default in Ember Data 1.x) or the JSONAPIAdapter (the default in Ember Data 2.x)?

Comment: @GJK I'm on Ember 1.13.7, using RESTAdapter. Should I give JSONAPIAdapter a try?

Comment: No the RESTAdapter should be fine, they just have slightly different functionality so I wanted to know before I answered your question. What you want to do is a process called "sideloading". I've got one more thing to do at work but when I'm done with that I'll write up an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a process called sideloading, which *should* work as you expect (I've had issues in the past with sideloading data). As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3090), you want to split your parts into two separate arrays.

```
{
    // These are the direct children
    "parts": [{...}, {...}],
    // These are the extra records
    "_parts": [{...}, {...}]
}
```